# VBA inserting an arrray formula in R1C1 notation gets messed up

Tags: excel, vba, array-formulas

I have a function that inserts an array formula into a spreadsheet using R1C1 style notation. When the code inserts the formula into the spreadsheet, all the references get messed up. This confuses me because from what I saw online the .FormulaArray property of a range accepts both A1 and R1C1 style. This is the formula I want to insert:

```
AddArrayFunction "HUB_START", "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(PACE!C10,MATCH(1,(PACE!C4=""New Hub"")*(PACE!C9=HubSummaryLTE!RC1),0))="""",""NO_DATE"",INDEX(PACE!C10,MATCH(1,(PACE!C4=""New Hub"")*(PACE!C9=HubSummaryLTE!RC1),0))),""NO_DATE"")", HubWS(Key) ' Make this an array formula
```

The double quotes are only there because of the way I pass the string to the function that actually inserts the formula down an entire column.
When the code writes to the Range.FormulaArray property, and I then go to the spreadsheet to look at the cell, it gives me this instead:

```
=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(PACE!R[8]C[-4],MATCH(1,(PACE!R[2]C[-4]="New Hub")*(PACE!R[7]C[-4]=HubSummaryLTE!R[-1]C[464]),0))="","NO_DATE",INDEX(PACE!R[8]C[-4],MATCH(1,(PACE!R[2]C[-4]="New Hub")*(PACE!R[7]C[-4]=HubSummaryLTE!R[-1]C[464]),0))),"NO_DATE")
```

I don't know why the references are getting messed up and I don't want to use A1 notation, any ideas?

Here's the calling code:

```
' HUB_START
AddArrayFunction "HUB_START", "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(PACE!C10,MATCH(1,(PACE!C4=""New Hub"")*(PACE!C9=HubSummaryLTE!RC1),0))="""",""NO_DATE"",INDEX(PACE!C10,MATCH(1,(PACE!C4=""New Hub"")*(PACE!C9=HubSummaryLTE!RC1),0))),""NO_DATE"")", HubWS(Key) ' Make this an array formula
```

And here is the function definition:

```
Sub AddArrayFunction(FormulaTitle As String, FormulaText As String, WS As Worksheet, Optional Row As Long = 1, Optional Column As Integer = -1)
    Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = FindLastUsedRow(WS) ' WS.Cells(WS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim PasteCol As Integer
    If Column < 0 Then
        PasteCol = 1
        Do Until WS.Cells(Row, PasteCol) = ""
            PasteCol = PasteCol + 1
        Loop
    Else
        PasteCol = Column
    End If
    If WS.Cells(Row, PasteCol) <> "" Then WS.Columns(PasteCol).Insert Shift:=xlShiftToRight
    WS.Cells(Row, PasteCol) = FormulaTitle
    WS.Range(WS.Cells(Row + 1, PasteCol), WS.Cells(LastRow, PasteCol)).FormulaArray = FormulaText
End Sub
```

The column with the header "HUB_START" has the formula that the code automatically puts in. The column next to it with no header, has the same exact formula, I just copied and pasted, then I did control shift enter just to test and it clearly works, so I don't know where the problem is coming from.
[image]

Comment: Might be useful to include your actual VBA?

Comment: change the `PACE!C9=HubSummaryLTE!RC1` to `PACE!C9=HubSummaryLTE!R[0]C1`  My guess is that is assuming A1 and not R1C1.  I believe by changing those two references it will default to R1C1 instead.

Comment: @Scott are you saying that FormulaArray Will accept either A1 or R1C1? And that if a formula string is both valid A1 and valid R1C1 it chooses A1 (as is the case here)?  If so, that would be a really useful answer (together with your solution to modify the string to be invalid A1 while maintaining the R1C1 meaning) - I can't find any MS references that explain this

Comment: @ScottCraner, your solution worked in terms of now when I click on the cell it contains the right references, however for some reason, the formula itself doesn't function the same way as if I did it manually by typing in the formula and doing control shift enter, it almost seems like it doesn't update because it says no "NO_DATE" for all cells indicating to me a possible error, where as when I type it manually and do C-S-E, it gives me the expected results. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: Step through the formula using Evaluate Formula on the Formula tab and see where it returns the error.

Comment: @ScottCraner, the interesting thing is, that when I copy and paste the exact same formula that the code automatically inserts and do C-S-E, it works, so the actual structure of the formula must be correct, it's just that when the code does it it doesn't work.

Comment: Oh..........I know.  You need to loop and not assign the formula to the full range as one.  Otherwise it is like highlighting the full range, putting the formula in the formula bar and hitting Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  it applies the same formula to the full range, expecting an array output to put in the cells.  You want to return a single value and as such the array formula needs to be applied to a single cell at a time.  Loop it.

Comment: That worked, thank you! @ScottCraner